# Transform an polygon from epsg:3413 to epsg:4326 in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, spatial-query, reprojection-error

My goal is using the polygon drawed by user under epsg:3413 as one args to find other polygons within.
While i transform the polygon simplely using ol.transform, some problems occured. If the north polar is overlapped under epsg:3413, the transform result under epsg:4326 would not.

```
this.draw.on('drawend', function(e) {
      e.feature.setId(e.feature.ol_uid)
      var geometry = e.feature.getGeometry()
      var geoCo = geometry.getCoordinates();
      geoCo = geoCo[0];
      var center_X = 0, center_Y = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < geoCo.length; i++) {
        geoCo[i] = transform(geoCo[i], document.getElementById('view-projection').getProjection(viewProjSelect.value).code_, 'EPSG:4326');
        geoCo[i][0] = geoCo[i][0].toFixed(4);
        geoCo[i][1] = geoCo[i][1].toFixed(4);
      }
      _self.ImageryArgs.geoInfo.corrdinates = geoCo;
      _self.map.removeInteraction(_self.draw)
    })
```

[the polygon under epsg:3413 which contains the north polar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXXnR.jpg)

[the polygon with same points and under epsg:4236, without containing the north polar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovMca.jpg)

I wonder if there any transform methods would make sure the result overlap the north polar in similar cases

Comment: You could produce a more detailed polygon by plotting the great circle linestring between each of your current vertices as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html  Note that arc.js will return multiple entries in the geometry array if the line crosses the 180 meridian.

Comment: Also where the edge of a polygon around a pole crosses the 180th meridian the polygon should be closed by going to the pole and back, for example 
`[178.277212,-84.472518],[180,-84.71338],[180,-90],[-180,-90],[-180,-84.71338],[-179.942499,-84.721443]` in the polygon for Antarctica from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson